# How to draw in X11 with Go

Tags: graphics, 2d, go

I've been looking into `draw` and `draw.x11` packages that come with Go. I didn't find out a simple way to draw a line on a X11 window.

Where I can find some simple 2D drawing examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found myself the answer, here it goes a simple example:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "time"
    "image"
    "exp/draw/x11"
)

func main() {
    win, _ := x11.NewWindow()
    color := image.RGBAColor{255, 255, 255, 255}

    img := win.Screen()
    for i, j := 0, 0; i < 100 && j < 100; i, j = i + 1, j + 1 {
        img.Set(i, j, color)
    }

    win.FlushImage()
    time.Sleep(10 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000)
    win.Close()
    os.Exit(0)
}
```

Comment: "exp/draw/x11" doesn't exist... ?

Comment: `exp/draw/x11` and `gui/x11` has been dropped from main go repo, and the effort has been moved to `code.google.com/p/x-go-binding/xgb`: http://code.google.com/p/x-go-binding/

Answer (score 3):

While your solution works, I think what you're really looking for is [X Go Binding](http://code.google.com/p/x-go-binding/)

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

import (    
    "fmt"
    "code.google.ui/x11"    // i'm not sure this is the actual package 
    "time"                  // name u better refer the packages
    "os"
)

func main() {
    win,err := x11.NewWindowArea(600,600)  // it creates a window with 600 width&600
    if err != nil {                        // height
        fmt.Println(err)  
        os.Exit(0)                         // if any err occurs it exits
    } 

    img :=win.Screen                       // in this newly created screen u cn draw
    for i:=0;i<100;i++ {                   // any thing pixel by pixel 
        for j:=0;j<100;j++ {
            img.Set(0+i,0+j,image.Black)   // now this draws a square in the black
        }                                  // color oo the created screen
    }

    win.FlushImage()                       // its for flushing the image then only new 
    time.Sleep(time.Second*15)             // image cn be draw
}
```